# Prepend comment to SASS/Compass output

Tags: css, ruby, configuration, sass, compass-sass

Is there a convenient way to have SASS automatically prepend a comment to the beginning of each CSS output file? Specifically, when using [Compasss](http://compass-style.org/) I'd like to stick a brief warning telling designers not to edit the CSS directly and to point them to instructions on getting started with Compass. I use an output style of `:compressed`, which strips out comments that are in the input SCSS/SASS file.

If there isn't a convenient way to do this then I'll submit an issue/patch. I was thinking of adding an [option](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options) named `:output_prefix` that takes a String that will be prepended to all output CSS files.

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for this and stumbles on your item: You can also keep a comment in the final file by making the first character of a comment the `!` character.

Comment: Note that this no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compressed strips out all comments. I suggest you put this in a property:

```
warning { do-not: "edit this file"; }
```

Regarding the proposed patch, I do not think this use case is compelling enough to warrant such a feature.

Answer (score 14):

From the SASS reference on [comments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments):

> When the first letter of a comment is !, the comment will be interpolated and always rendered into css output even in compressed output modes. This is useful for adding Copyright notices to your generated CSS.

So you could start your SASS file with something like this:

```
/*!
 * WARNING: Don't edit this file by hand! Instead, you should be using Compass.
 * (More information at http://compass-style.org/)
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Known bug in Sass.  Fixed in master but not yet released:

https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/784